# Hexadecimal values in perl

Tags: linux, perl, scripting, hex

I have a text file that I am reading and every line has a hex value which I want to store in a variable.

For eg - Suppose a line is of the form "mytext 1c" then I want to store "1c" in a variable and then perform some calculations involving hexadecimal values.

How can I do this using Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a line on whitespace, you can use [`split ' '`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split).

```perl
my @fields = split(' ', $line);   # In $fields[1]
```

or

```perl
my $hex = ( split(' ', $line) )[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

According your example, there is a key + space(s) + hex value:

```
my $line = "mytext 1c";
my ($key, $value) = split /\s+/, $line;  # Regexpr to handle 1 or more whitespaces
```

Now, if you want to do arithmetic operations, use [hex function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex) to transform `$value` to a number:

```
my $sum = hex($value) + 1;
printf "%x\n", $sum;       # <- prints: 1d
```